# C struct padding

Tags: c

I can use pragma pack on various compilers to force structs to have fields which are not on their natural alignments.

Is this recursive - so suppose struct typedef A contains a field of typedef struct B. If use a pragma to pack A will this force struct B to be packed?

Comment: @shipshere:Not sure if it is valid for all compilers but I think that members of structures are aligned on the specified byte-alignment, or on their natural alignment boundary, whichever of the two is less

Answer (score 6):

You have to hope not! Lets say you have a function that takes a parameter struct A:

```
void fn( struct A x ) ;
```

and then a packed struct B that has struct A as a member:

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct B
{
    struct A a ; 
}
```

If you pass the member a of B to fn(), the function has no knowledge of the packing in this instance, and would fail.

Other answerer's results notwithstanding, I performed the following test on VC++ 2010:

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    char b;
    int c ;
} ;

struct B
{
    struct A  d ;
} ;

#pragma pack(1)
struct C
{
    struct A  d ;
} ;


#pragma pack(1)
struct D
{
    int a;
    char b;
    int c ;
} ;

#pragma pack(1)
struct E
{
    struct D ;
} ;

int main()
{
    int a = sizeof(struct A) ;
    int b = sizeof(struct B) ;
    int c = sizeof(struct C) ;
    int d = sizeof(struct D) ;
    int e = sizeof(struct E) ;
}
```

Inspection of a, b, c, d and e in main() in the debugger yield:

- a = 12
- b = 12
- c = 12
- d = 9
- e = 9

The packing of `struct C` has no effect on the size of its struct A member.

Answer (score 5):

**Just don't.** The exact behavior of an ugly nonstandard extension is not something you can even ask questions about without specifying an exact platform/compiler you're working with. If you find yourself needing packed structs, you'd be better to figure out why your code is broken and fix it. Packed structs are a band-aid for broken code that do nothing to fix the root cause of the brokenness.

Comment: @R...:Why is a band-aid for broken code? Packed structures are used for memory conservation especially in embedded systems. So what do you mean?

Comment: Sometimes they're necessary. Want to cleanly represent a packet whose fields aren't all word-aligned in C? You can use a packed struct or a whole crap-ton of macros. That said, I've seen some nasty compiler bugs related to recursive packed structs. Shudder.

Comment: @Nathon: Using structs for binary IO is broken. `#pragma packed` will not fix endian dependencies and such. Write a proper serialize function. @user384706: On any system but x86, the amount of extra code to read and write the non-aligned fields will be a lot larger than the few bytes wasted in the structure - especially if you fix the ordering of your elements so that they naturally align right with no padding requirements. Hint: `alignof(type)` divides `sizeof(type)` for all types.

Comment: Write a proper serialize function...or just use appropriate endian conversion functions to ensure endian correctness when accessing fields where it matters. Gratuitous appeal to authority: `__attribute__ ((packed))` appears 3162 times in the Linux kernel headers and 444 more times in the rest of the sources.

Comment: Sometimes a packed structure needs to be used to handle a memory-mapped I/O device.

Comment: @Darron: A packed structure never "needs to be used". You can use portable pointer arithmetic. For any modern hardware, MMIO registers will be aligned anyway and you can use a normal, non-packed struct. @Nathon: I suspect most of these uses are gratuitous and change nothing about the storage of the struct. Most of the rest are probably for packed bitfields which are bad for a completely different reason.

Comment: @R: pointer arithmetic or packed structures are both possible answers to a fundamentally non-portable problem.  Choosing between them is a matter of style.  I feel a packed structure that matches the hardware documentation can be more readable.

Comment: @Darron: Barring intentional breakage by an implementor, the pointer arithmetic solution is portable to any compiler for the cpu architecture you're working on. On the other hand, packed structures depend on nonstandard *syntax* which will necessarily be compiler-specific.

Answer (score 4):

Folowing Nathon's post, I tried about the same thing on my computer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if defined PACK_FIRST || defined PACK_BOTH
#pragma pack(1)
#endif
struct inner {
  char a;
  double b;
};

#if defined PACK_SECOND || defined PACK_BOTH
#pragma pack(1)
#endif
struct outer {
  char a;
  struct inner b;
  char c;
  double d;
};

int main(void) {
  printf("sizeof (char): %d (1, of course)\n", (int)sizeof (char));
  printf("sizeof (double): %d\n", (int)sizeof (double));
  printf("sizeof (inner): %d\n", (int)sizeof (struct inner));
  printf("sizeof (outer): %d\n", (int)sizeof (struct outer));
  return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc 4128061.c
$ ./a.out 
sizeof (char): 1 (1, of course)
sizeof (double): 8
sizeof (inner): 16
sizeof (outer): 40
$ gcc -DPACK_FIRST 4128061.c
$ ./a.out 
sizeof (char): 1 (1, of course)
sizeof (double): 8
sizeof (inner): 9
sizeof (outer): 19
$ gcc -DPACK_SECOND 4128061.c
$ ./a.out 
sizeof (char): 1 (1, of course)
sizeof (double): 8
sizeof (inner): 16
sizeof (outer): 26
$ gcc -DPACK_BOTH 4128061.c
$ ./a.out 
sizeof (char): 1 (1, of course)
sizeof (double): 8
sizeof (inner): 9
sizeof (outer): 19
```

Apparently my gcc packs from the point where the `#pragma` line appears.

Comment: Doesn't the first #pragma pack(1) apply to both structs, even if triggered by PACK_FIRST? i.e. your ifdefs do nothing unless you use pragma pack(push,1), followed by pragma(pop) before the second struct definition

Answer (score 1):

For the version of GCC I have handy, it looks like yes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct
{
    char a;
    int  b;
}inner_t;
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct
{
    char a;
    inner_t inner;
} outer_t;

int main()
{
    outer_t outer;

    outer.inner.a = 'a';
    outer.inner.b = 0xABCDEF01;
    printf ("outer.inner.a: %c\n", outer.inner.a);
    return 0;
}
```

And gdb breaking on the printf gives me...

```
(gdb) x/5xw &outer
0x7fffffffe4b0: 0xffff61a0      0xcdef01ff      0x000000ab      0x00000000
0x7fffffffe4c0: 0x00000000
```

`inner.b` is not word aligned. So under GCC 4.4.5 on a little endian 64-bit machine, nested structures are packed if the outer structure is packed. Pardon my typedefs, those of you who don't like them.