# how to pack a structure inside a structure

Tags: c, compiler-construction, padding, linux-device-driver

Let me more clear,
 I want to pad an internal structure how do I do it..? Example-

where `struct b` is

```
struct b{
  u_int32_t aa;
  u_int32_t bb;
};

struct c{
  u_int64_t cc;
};
```

Now, my compiler is doing a padding of 8 byte between the struct b and c in struct d. So, how do i get rid of that?

Hope, it clear now. Can somebody give me a answer?

structure d{

```
struct b;

struct c; //I want to make this structure a padded one, how to go about it?

struct c;

}
```

Please, can somebody help me with this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C struct padding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128061/c-struct-padding)

Comment: What compiler are you using? GCC uses `__attribute__` while MSVC uses `#pragma`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the tags, I deduce you're on linux. GCC recognizes the following attribute:

```
__attribute__((packed))
```

which you can write before or after the declaration of the struct to remove the padding.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, **it is not placing any padding** between b and c.

Let us see why,

All `u_int32_t` are 32 bits => 4 bytes. Now the size of `struct b` will be 8 bytes (4 because of aa and 4 because of bb). Also, the size of `struct c` is  8 bytes as well.

So when `struct d` is made, both `struct b` and `struct c` are placed sequentially one after the other. The next `struct c` is placed directly after the previous `struct c`.

But **there is a 8 byte padding after the final** `struct c` and the closure of `struct d`. And this is because, if multiple `struct d` are to be placed in memory the second `struct d` will end up starting from the memory location of 24 and not 32 (which is convinient).

If you wish for more info: [The Lost Art of C Structure Packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/)