# Why the size of this structure is same irrespective of the order of the members?

Tags: c, alignment, structure, sizeof

As memory alignment of the structure in C is done in a contiguous form for the first element first and then second, then third and so on... along with bit padding, then why the size of this structure is same even when the elements are rearranged:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct student
    {
        float c;
        int a;
        char b;
    };
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(struct student));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
`12`

Does the memory alignment looks like this for the above configuration of structure?:

```
f f f f i i i i c
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: Why do you think the size wouldn't be the same?  What ordering of fields would you expect to have a different size?

Comment: As by rearranging the members, the order of the memory allotment changes. i.e. first element will be different in that case and so does the memory taken by the `structure` As in the case of this structure: 
    struct student
    {
        int b;
        char a;
        char c;
    };

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that on your machine both `int` and `float` require 4 bytes each. In this sense, their location in the `struct` is irrelevant.

However, a `char` takes (usually) only 1 byte, so you might wonder how come `sizeof` doesn't return `9` (4+4+1) and the reason is **padding**.

Padding is added in a number of situations, but most obviously to allow for type alignment (I assume that both the `int` and `float` types on your system are naturally aligned on the 4 byte boundary).

I assume that this would make perfect sense if the order was changed to:

```
struct student
{
    float c;
    char b;
    int a;
};
```

In this example we would have 4 bytes (`float`) + 1 byte (`char`) + 3 bytes (padding) + 4 bytes (`int`). i.e.:

```
struct student
{
    float c;
    char b;
    char padding[3];
    int a;
};
```

However, in your original example we have:

```
struct student
{
    float c;
    int a;
    char b;
};
```

This results in 4 bytes (`float`) + 4 bytes (`int`) + 1 byte (`char`) + 3 bytes (padding) - i.e.:

```
struct student
{
    float c;
    int a;
    char b;
    char padding[3];
};
```

The reason we still get padding at the end of the `struct` is to allow for Arrays (`struct student array[32]`).

If there wasn't any padding at the end of the `struct` than the second member of the array (`array[1]`) would start on an offset and the type (`float`) wouldn't be properly aligned on the natural 4 byte boundary.

When you declare the type, the compiler will always add the required padding that allows the type to be used in an array (i.e., when allocating memory using `malloc`).

I hope this answers your question.

---

**EDIT**:

To clarify the padding in the remaining `struct` that I hadn't listed above (see comment), it would probably look something like this (assuming the compiler is compiling code for a similar system):

```
struct student
{
    char b;
    char padding[3];
    float c;
    int a;
};
```

If `a` was a `char` as well, we would get padding in both ends of the `struct`:

```
struct student
{
    char b;
    char padding[3];
    float c;
    char a;
    char padding2[3];
};
```

However, if we re-organized the `struct` so the chars were next to each other, their padding would be different since the `char` type doesn't have a natural alignment of 4 bytes on this system:

```
struct student
{
    char b;
    char a;
    char padding[2];
    float c;
};
```

**Note**:

Most compilers should support an instruction that tells the compiler to "pack" the structure (ignore type alignment and padding)... this, however, should be highly discouraged IMHO since it could cause some CPU architectures to crash and introduces non-portable code ([see also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128061/c-struct-padding)).

Comment: Can you tell me how the padding is done in this structure then?
    `struct student
{
        char b;
        int a;
        char c;
    };`
Size showing is `12`

Comment: @Neeraj-Kumar-Coder - I edited the answer with response to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

On your system, the `int` and `float` data types appear to have sizes of 4 bytes each; thus, the compiler (unless told otherwise) will align structure members of those types on 4-byte boundaries. This is why, if you have the `char b` field as the *second* member, then 3 bytes of 'padding' will be added between that and the next field - giving a total size of 12 bytes for the structure.

**However, the compiler will also add padding at the end of the structure!** (Three bytes, again, in the case when `char b` is the last field.)

**Why?** Well, consider an array of such `struct` types. Without that 'terminal padding', the first field of the second array element would be misaligned – that is, it would *not* be on a 4-byte boundary, thus reducing any efficiency gained from 'internal' padding. Similar issues would arise for other structures that have your type included as a nested field.

EDIT: I can't really offer much improvement on the following statement from [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment):

> It is important to note that the last member is padded with the number
> of bytes required so that the total size of the structure should be a
> multiple of the largest alignment of any structure member …

Comment: How the padding is done for this `struct`:
`struct sample
{
char b;
int a;
char c;
};`
Size showing is `12`

Comment: @Neeraj-Kumar-Coder Again, very similar: 3 bytes after `b` and 3 bytes after `c`.

Comment: @Neeraj-Kumar-Coder But this one will be different: `struct sample { char b; char c; int a; };` ... just 2 bytes padding after `c`, giving a total size of 8 bytes.

Comment: It means if `char` is in the last member then only the extra padding is done.
Also in the example of my comment, the first member will not be misaligned if extra padding is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler aligns the fields and fills the remainder of the `struct` so if you build an array, the next element will be aligned.

In your posted case, the alignment of the field elements is the size of the two fields `float` and `int` that are 4 bytes large.  So the compiler pads the structure at the end for the next array element of the type you are defined is also aligned.  This means the compiler has to add three pad elements after the `char`  typed field, even if it is at the end of the structure.

In the case you post, if you consider that the struct is 5 bytes, the next element of an array of structs will not be aligned, as the float and the int would start on a `+1` aligned offset.